Two dimensional colormap for comparing angles
I have data on a 2D structured grid. At every grid node I have a unit length vector. So far it is a regular quiver plot.
For every vector I consider it's angle (with reference to the x-axis). The change of this angle from one vector to its right neighbor is the first value that I would like to visualize.
The change of angle to its upper neighbor is the second.
So far I have just used two separate quiver plots to illustrate this. One colored according to the horizontal change the other for the vertical change. But I don't like this solution to much as it takes a lot of space an duplicates the information about the vectors on the grid.
I also thought of using a two dimensional colormap. Something like this: https://colorstamps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
I wonder if that is very readable in the end though.
If you have any ideas for how I should visualize my data?
Here is a small example of the data:

The goal would be to "merge" the two plots, as they have a lot of redundant information (the arrows are the same).

Hey Franz. You use a lot of technical, non-graphic design, terms in this post. It might help if you simplified some of the language. Additionally, it would be good to include 1. examples of the data / plots that you have, 2. what you have tried, 3. what your goals of the visualization are, and 4. where what you have tried falls short. Perhaps our critique guidelines might help you form a question that we can answer more easily

Hey @ZachSaucier.
I added an example image. Maybe this community has an idea on what could be done but possibly this is just not the right place to ask. Ty anyway.

The idea that you want to measure a vector, reminded me the Normal Maps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping

Much better question! Thanks for editing
